# Proving the continuity of the second order derivative of the solution to $\dot{X} =AX$?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, dynamical-systems

In case of a say $n \geq 1$ dimensional system, $\dot{X} =AX$, where $X$ is the $n \times 1$ dimensional vector and $A $ is a $n \times n$ square matrix. The initial condition is specified as $X(0) = X_{0}$.

Now I was thinking about this  - If $X(t)$ is a solution on the interval $I$, then how do we prove that the 'double derivative ' of $X$ that is $\frac{d^{2}X}{dt^2}$ is also continuous on $I$?

How do we prove this? only idea coming to mind here is  - Differentiability  implies Continuity and not the converse. So since $\dot{X}$ exists so it is differentiable, so $\dot{X}$ is continuous, now since $\dot{X}$ is continuous but yet we donot know about the differentiability  of $\dot{X}$ that is the double derivative? still we want to prove the continuityof the double derivative of $X$ on $I$?

Comment: First, in case $A$ is constant $X$ can be solved explicitly as $e^{At}c_0$. Then, you only have to work out $X"$ explicitly.

Comment: Oh, then we have $\dot{X} = X_{0}e^{At}$, $\frac{d^2X}{dt^2} = A^2 X_{0}e^{At}$?, then how do we show the continuity of $A^2 X_{0}e^{At}$?, does that simply follow from the existence of double derivative of $X$?

Comment: Can you say something about $\frac d{dt} (AX)$?

Comment: is that $A\dot{X}$ which is also $A^2 X$?

Comment: @BAYMAX Indeed. Conclude that $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}X=A\dot X=A^2X$

Comment: So how the continuity of the second order derivative of $X$ follows? is it because $\frac{d^2X}{dt^2}$ exists which implies their continuity??

Comment: If you differentiate both sides of the equation you can compare the LHS and the RHS back and forth. If one side is continuous, the so is the other.  Since one side always depends on derivatives of order lower then the other side you are done.

Comment: Be careful with the order of the terms: $\dot X=e^{At}X_0$, not $X_0e^{At}$ (which does not exist), likewise, $\ddot X=Ae^{At}X_0=e^{At}AX_0$ or $\ddot X=A\dot X=A^2X$, but neither $AX_0e^{At}$ nor $A^2X_0e^{At}$ (which do not exist).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Alan Muniz's comment:

Suppose you want to solve an ODE of the form $\dot{x}(t)=F(x(t))$, where $x$ should be a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F\in C^K(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n)$.  A strong solution has at least one derivative; i.e. $x\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n)$.  I claim that in fact $x\in C^{K+1}$.

To see this, work by induction.  Suppose $x$ has $k$ derivatives, with $k\leq K$.  Since the existence of derivatives is preserved by function composition (that's the chain rule), we have $F\circ x\in C^k$.  But $\dot{x}=F\circ x$, so $x$ has a $(k+1)$<sup>st</sup> derivative.  Now repeat until $k=K+1$.